# Need a java library for visualization that support automatic layout

Tags: java, layout, graph

I need a java graph library for  visualization that I can incorporate in my own application. I found that jgraph is excellent for visualization but require explicit positioning of the nodes. Is there any open source java graph library that support automatic layout. Any suggestion will be really helpful for me.

Comment: You want an open source library that you can just point to a data source and have it draw, but how will it know where to appear? Do you just tell it what jpanel to be in? Explaining how you want to use it may be useful.

Comment: Thx for the reply. 
I have found that Jung(http://jung.sourceforge.net) support auto layout where one need to only specify the structure of the graph. The layout of the graph is done by the library.  Graphviz also can produce excellent graph output but possibly can not be incorporated directly to the application.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous packages to do that.
If you are used to [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), then you may like [Grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/), which is a sort of graphviz library for java (though not as complete as the original).

[jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) is also quite good, providing various layout engines.

Another tool of interest to build nice graph visualizations and animations is [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/). It it very flexible, and can lead to very good looking visualizations, with complex layouts.

All of them are java libraries, and open source.

Answer (score 2):

I've used JGo for years with success - not free (has free eval).

http://www.nwoods.com/go/jgo.htm

It has autolayout options for digraphs and force-directed, for sure, maybe more.  I think the newer versions are much spiffier.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I have found that Jung possibly a solution for my problem. It support auto layout and it is open source. I will try JGo also.

Answer (score 0):

JGraph does support automatic layout and includes a number of graph and hieracichal layout algorithms.

See the API reference and example code for details.

Comment: there is no section 7. jGraph is pretty much useless for automatic layout, i can see there are a lot of classes for layout but there is no clue about how to use them.

Comment: Their documentation has changed since I responded to this question nearly a year ago. Your best bet is to download it and look at the source code, examples and API reference guide or switch to a better documented product.