# Library to get graph node coordinates

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to draw a graph from which I only know the distances between the nodes. I want to get the coordinates of the nodes but not an image with the nodes already drawn because I have to manipulate the node to add a little animation after that.

I like to find something like the [plain output of graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d%3aplain) but with a Java library that doesn't require native code.

Comment: You could try writing your own solution using simulated annealing if no suitable library exists. Do the node coordinates have to be perfectly to scale?

Comment: No, the node doesn't have to be perfectly scaled but the lines which connect them should not overlap

Comment: Have you checked the libraries mentioned in answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936548/need-a-java-library-for-visualization-that-support-automatic-layout?

Comment: I've checked but I haven't found one with which I can retrieve the coordinate of edges.

Comment: @claudex That may not be possible for all graphs, but simulated annealing should find such a solution if one exists.